# Wordpress undefined index notice in child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

When I add items to my menus in my wordpress child theme I get this error;

```
Notice: Undefined index: custom_meta_box_nonce in /Users/x/Documents/Apart-1/website 3/wp-content/themes/wp-foundation/functions.php on line 546
```

A link to my full base theme's function file is here; (again, I did not touch/write/ that.)
http://codepad.org/dAx0DlLz

This is around line 546 in my base theme;

```
// Save the Data
```

function save_homepage_meta($post_id) {
    global $custom_meta_fields;

```
// verify nonce  
if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['custom_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))  
    return $post_id;  
// check autosave  
if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)  
    return $post_id;  
// check permissions  
if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {  
    if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))  
        return $post_id;  
    } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {  
        return $post_id;  
}
```

And this is exactly on line 546;

```
if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['custom_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))
```

And this is in my child theme's function file;

```
    <?php
ob_start();
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { add_image_size( 'orbit-custom', 920, 300 ); }

/**
 * Add a search bar to the navigation menu.
 *
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */
function menu_search($items){
    $search = '<li class="menusearch">';
    $search .= '<form method="get" id="searchform" action="/">';
    $search .= '<input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search" />';
    $search .= '<input type="submit" class="menusubmit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />';
    $search .= '</form>';
    $search .= '</li>';

    return $items . $search;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','menu_search');

// This adds multiple menu locations
add_action( 'init', 'register_multiple_menus' );
function register_multiple_menus() {
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'footer-nav-mid' =>  'Middle Footer Navigation',
            'footer-nav-left' =>  'Left Footer Navigation',
            'footer-nav-right' =>  'Right Footer Navigation'
        )
    );
}

 ?>
```

Why am I getting this error? I did not change anything to my base theme's function file and did not get this error before adding the multiple menu thing to my child's function file.

Comment: are u adding nonce to the custom meta box? show the metabox as well

Comment: I added a link to the full functions file of the base theme I used, I did not edit that functions file though, it came complete with the base theme called 'wp-foundation'.

Comment: error appeared in save_homepage_meta when u added to search and nav functions to child theme?code you added will not affect in anyway to the save_post... check the plugin must be overided

Comment: I did not add any plugins that have anything to do with the menus or saving posts... The error appears in the screen where you can add new menus, the moment I click save or add an item to the menu.

Comment: if you try to save the menu ..then it is also saving post..it should not happen.. something is hooked in some page check!..

Comment: I'm not skilled enough in php and wordpress to even know what to look for, can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

For `undefined index` notices normally the solution is using `isset()`:

```
if ( 
    !isset( $_POST['custom_meta_box_nonce'] ) 
    || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['custom_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__) ) 
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately after working on my site I get the exact same error again, the isset thing isn't solving it anymore..

Comment: it means that I edited my child theme and child theme's function file after adding the isset thing to my main theme's function file yesterday. The message says the error is in the main theme's function file again though, I don't see how it gives the same error again even if I didn't touch the main theme's function file...

Comment: Is there anything you can update in the Question? Is it all exactly the same?

Comment: Everything except for my child theme's function file but it says that the problem is in the main theme's function file.. I'll check my previous main function file again to see if I forgot about editing something... -- I edited a credit line on the top of the file, this is the new version; http://codepad.org/rVTqQ77I

Comment: Sorry, but the solution is doing the `isset`. Double check the names for typos. Notices are not that important, of course better not to have them. You probably have `WP_DEBUG` enabled in your wp-config.php and in live sites you should re-direct the messages to a file with the [LOG and DISPLAY options](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress).

Comment: There are no typos in the names regarding custom meta box nonce or the innit... Also, I already have the innit in the right way since it worked before. I get the error message 'Notice: Undefined index: custom_meta_box_nonce in /Users/x/Documents/Apart-1/website/wp-content/themes/wp-foundation/functions.php on line 546' 3 times..